# How to find a certain phrase from multiple folders in a folder Powershell

Tags: powershell

Good Afternoon

so This code can find certain phrase if I know which folder is

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\k1\Desktop\test\New folder'  |Select-String -Pattern "apple"

Desktop\test\New folder\Courses Taught Fac:apple
```

but if in "test" folder, there are many folders, but I do not know which folders in it, but I know certain phrase on some text files in some folders in "test" folder.

how can I code this situation?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description it sounds like you just need to add the -Recurse parameter to your command

Answer (score 1):

Searching through all subdirectories will be done when the `-Recurse` switch is used. Using `-Filter` will prevent looking through every file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\k1\Desktop\test\New folder' -Recurse -File -Filter '*.txt' |
    Select-String -Pattern "apple"
```